# Moving web application to default port on IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, port, asp.net-mvc

I'm a newbie to servers and deployment so I was wondering if someone could help me. I have a web application running on a server running windows 2008 and IIS 7. At the moment the app is running on port 85 of the web server.

I want to change this to the default port as I want it to run under a domain name address.

This web application is very complex and deals with many databases which are also held on the server.

If I change ports will this have any negative affects on the application?

Any advice is appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any links in your web app that are hard coded to port 85, obviously those will break.  However, if it is well written using relative URLs, and where necessary using a config script to deal with the hostname:port part of the URL (which you can update), then you should be fine.

If you are running in a development environment, you should change the port number in IIS and check to see what happens.  If you are using a different port because you developed on the production server then your job will be a bit more difficult, with a higher risk of end users seeing issues.  If they do, then you probably made a good case for a development environment for future development :-)